# Standart Input on multiple lines

Tags: java, cmd

I'm a beginner at Java. I write that piece of code to compile it on CMD.

```
public class AA {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int line=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int i=0;
        while(i<line){
            double first_input = StdIn.readDouble();
            double second_input = StdIn.readDouble();
            double third_input = StdIn.readDouble();
            double average = first_input * 0.2 + second_input * 0.4 + third_input * 0.4;
            line-=1
            StdOut.println(average+"is..");
        }
    }
}
```

Although I'm looking for this:

```
2 15 22
2 5 77 
15,2 is...
33,2 is...
```

the output I got is just like this:

```
  2 15 22 
  15,2 is...
  2 5 77
  33,2 is...
```

I tried many ways but I got no solution. Are there some tricks that I cannot see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirements as I understand it, I would add the calculated values to a variable and then once you have input all the values, display the stored value.

Naturally there are multiple ways of achieving this goal but maybe a simple one is using a StringBuffer.

```
    public static void main( String[] args )
{
    int line = Integer.parseInt( args[ 0 ] );
    int i = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while ( i < line )
    {
        double first_input = StdIn.readDouble();
        double second_input = StdIn.readDouble();
        double third_input = StdIn.readDouble();
        double average = first_input * 0.2 + second_input * 0.4 + third_input * 0.4;
        sb.append( average );
        sb.append( " is..\n" );
        line -= 1;
    }
    StdOut.println( sb.toString() );
}
```

FYI, it seems that the OP is using the library http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/ and that it is designed to take one argument, which is the number of iterations to run.